# Mi pagina no conecta a mi base de datos

Tags: php, sql

Me intento conectar a mi base de datos del siguiente modo:

```
mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);
```

Se que mysql esta obsoleto pero como uso una version antigua xampp deberia funcionar. Sin embargo, mi pagina nunca termina de cargar y se queda siempre a la espera.

Inicio la sesion del siguiente modo:

```
<?php
@session_start();
if (isset($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {

    include_once("includes/config.php");

    if ($admin_user == $_POST['user']) {
        if ($admin_password == sha1($_POST['pass'])) {
            $_SESSION['login'] = true;
            header("Location: stats.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Alguien podria decir como puedo debuguear este codigo para conseguir que arranca correctamente?

Comment: Con que versión de php estas trabajando ?

Comment: php 4 estoy trbajando

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la funcion error_reporting(E_ALL), te recomiendo poner un exit() despues del mysql_connect para saber si es ahi donde queda a la espera.

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que utilices `mysqli`

archivo `conexion.php`

```
<?php

  DEFINE ('DB_USUARIO','user');
  DEFINE ('DB_CLAVE','pass');
  DEFINE ('DB_HOST','localhost');
  DEFINE ('DB_NOMBRE','database');
   $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USUARIO,DB_CLAVE,DB_NOMBRE);
   mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
 ?>
```

simplemente en tus archivos externos mandalo llamar de la siguiente forma:

```
include('conexion.php');
```

Si necesitas hacer una consulta con lo siguiente:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO...");
```